# Update field based on current time in mondodb

Tags: mongodb, time, field

Is there a way in mongodb to "auto update" a field based on the current time ?

To be more specific I have a collection called "Store", the schema is as follow :

```
name: String,
type : String,
lat: Number, 
lng: Number,
infos : {
  description : String
},
isOpen : Boolean
```

For all my stores in my Store collection I want isOpen to be true from 8am to 8pm and false from 8pm to 8am.

Is it possible for mongodb to auto update these fields based on the current time and how can I do that ?

Thanks for your responses and sorry if I'm not specific enough and if my english is not very good.

PS : I'm using the mongoose module in Node

Comment: I'd suggest a schema change for this functionality. What you could do is store the open hours and then run a query in a way which will automatically give you a true/false value rather than trying to keep the database dynamically up to date depending on the current time of day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. Data in MongoDB doesn't change outside of update operations.

You'll have to do some (very light) processing on your application server to achieve what you want.

Comment: No. Whenever you're fetching a document from the database, before returning it to the client, change whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by running a cron job. If you are using Node, You can check [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron). Just run a cron job at 8am to change value of isOpen to true and run another cron job at 8pm to change the value to false